# Finding current value of a python list

Tags: python

I have a never ending python script that runs continuously.
Inside the script, I am using a LIST type (ex: JOB_LIST).

In few scenario's I want to know the elements(values) present in JOB_LIST at current point of time without stopping the execution of the script(Don't have any appropriate rights to stop the script)

How can this be done? Is there any command line option (or) can we write another script to print Current state of JOB_LIST from already executing script?

Comment: Output to a file? Or print to the console?

Comment: Output to File will do

Comment: Ah -- so you can't stop the job or alter the code?  You need to do this from the outside?

Comment: yes...I have to do that from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a Signal Handler:

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    # Write JOB_LIST to a file

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
```

Signal your running Script to write `JOB_LIST` to a `file`.

```
# pid = Process ID of your running Script
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
```

Comment: It worked...I am able to print on the console as well as write to a file.Also, based on the signal received, I am able to do necessary action.